# Bug on Break Page Simple List Html

Tags: html, css, page-break

I Have a problem when my list is break page on print

My css:

```
    table {
    page-break-after: auto !important
}

tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    page-break-after: auto !important
}

td {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    page-break-after: auto !important
}

thead {
    display: table-header-group !important
}

tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group !important
}
```

My HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Quant.</th>
        <th>Cod.</th>
        <th>Mantenimiento</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of getData()"> <!-- Dynamic Generate Rows-->
        <td>{{data?.quant}}</td>
        <td>{{data?.codItem}}</td>
        <td>{{data?.item}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot></table>
```

but my page contains bugs on break

[image: Image example when my list break page]

I'm dynamically generating lines, which break when there are many records, so I need a healthy break

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @showdev it was just a simple list, I thought it was not necessary, but I added.